# Is there a way to view the built-in documentation in C++?

Tags: c++, stl

I just started to learn C++ this month.

In Python, I can view the documentation of a built-in function (for example, `str.find`) by using `help(str.find)`.

However, I've no idea about how to view the documentation of `std::find` in `<algorithm>`, for example.

Does anyone have ideas about a quick way to look up documentation of a function in C++?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/

Comment: BTW, there is no such header as `algorithm.h` in C++. So, yes, you need some documentation.

Comment: Nobody else seems to really have mentioned getting a good IDE, I know that code::blocks shows some brief documentation while you type (along with autocomplete), but probably so to do other popular IDEs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C++ doesn't have built-in documentation like Python.

The most comprehensive online reference guide is [**C++ reference**](http://www.cppreference.com/), which covers the last three standards. This is not the top hit on most search engines but the top hit is full of inaccuracies and should be avoided.

You can also [download archives of the site for offline viewing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/Cppreference%3aArchives) (English link).

> Does anyone have ideas about a quick way to look up documentation of a function in C++?

In Google Chrome, I have a [search engine set up](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95653) with the keyword "`cpp`" and the URL "`http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=%s`" so that I can type <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>
 in the address bar to find details of [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3aSearch&search=std%3a%3afind%28%29) in my browser.

Answer (score 3):

C++ itself doesn't have "built-in documentation" per se. It is *a language*, not a system. Sure, Python is "just a language" too, but it's also an interpreter and this interpreter has certain features that C++ compilers don't have.

On Linux you **may** find *manpages* for what you need, because *libstdc++* (GCC's C++ standard library implementation) installs them:

```
man std::string
```

C++ documentation may be found canonically at:

- http://cppreference.com (peer-reviewed and well-regarded)
- [Your C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) (peer-reviewed by SO)
- The C++ standard (authoritative)

You should **not** use:

- Wikipedia
- SGI STL documentation (the SGI STL is *not* the same as the C++ Standard Library)
- http:// cplusplus.com

Comment: To be fair, cplusplus.com has been improving too (perhaps thanks to the competition from cppreference), and is quick to react to error reports (even minute ones, like 'you said unspecified where it says undefined')

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as builtin documentation in C++. You may have some documentation that comes with you compiler, but that is mainly for commercial products and vendor specific. You are best off using google to find your site of choice.